# Erro com arrays em Java

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me dizer o que tem de errado nesse código? O resultado é sempre o 1º número antes do espaço, mas tem que ser a soma de todos os números da array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = entrada.next();
    String array[] = x.split (" ");
    int soma = 0;
    int resultado[] = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        resultado[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
        soma = soma + resultado[i];
    }
    System.out.println (soma);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sempre 1? não não! acabei de fazer um teste e deu 2. Dá sempre o primeiro número da sequência.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque isso:

```
String x = entrada.next();
```

por isso

```
String x = entrada.nextLine();
```

O seu código não está funcionando, pois **next()** retorna o próximo token completo. Nesse caso, o 1o número antes do espaço. Já o **nextLine()** retorna todos os caracteres até o caracter de quebra de linha.

**Explicação mais detalhada**

Um token completo, retornado pelo **next()**, é um token que atenda o padrão de delimitação especificado no Scanner. Como não foi especificado nenhum padrão, então o espaço entre os números fica sendo um delimitador.

Por isso, ao digitar **1 2 3** e usar o **next()**, ele retorna o caracter 1, pois o espaço após o número 1 serviu de delimitador.

Já no caso no **nextLine** um padrão de linha é utilizado. Veja a função nextLine() retirada do código fonte da classe Scanner.

```
public String nextLine() {
    if (hasNextPattern == linePattern())
        return getCachedResult();
    clearCaches();

    String result = findWithinHorizon(linePattern, 0);
    if (result == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");
    MatchResult mr = this.match();
    String lineSep = mr.group(1);
    if (lineSep != null)
        result = result.substring(0, result.length() - lineSep.length());
    if (result == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else
        return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 - Muito boa a explicação, parabéns!

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo é que o `entrada.next();` retorna a práxima palavra, mas no contexto dessa aplicação seria `entrada.nextLine();`

`nextLine` pega tudo que foi digitado.